# Differentiation and integration of power series

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, power-series

I'm learning calculus and my textbook states that:

> A power series can be differentiated or integrated term by term over
>   an interval contained entirely within its interval of convergence. In
>   the case of differentiation, an open interval is required.

I don't get it. For example, I am not sure what they mean by "an interval contained entirely within its interval of convergence".

Could anybody explain what they are actually trying to say, the reasons behind it (i.e. why different intervals are required), and give some examples of what is legal and what not?

Comment: First of all, you need to know that all the points at which a power series converges must be an interval or a single point. Denoting it by $I$, then what the author tries to say is that: if $(a,b)\subset I$, term by term differention is legal on $(a,b)$; if $[a,b]\subset I$, term by term integration is legal on $[a,b]$.